# how to resolve : error Unable to load FFprobe

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I keep getting an error saying "unable to load FFprobe" Am I doing something wrong? here is my code and by the way I am using Laravel

```
 public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, array([
      'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt',

    ]));

    $viddy=new Video;

    //get the user requested file
     $vid = $request->file('video');

     //convert that file
     $feefee=FFMPEG::convert()->input($vid)->bitrate(300, 'video')->output('bar.flv')->go();


      $filename = $feefee->getClientOriginalName();
      $path = $feefee->storeAs('introvideo',$filename);
      $location = public_path('/vids',$filename);
      $feefee->move($location);
      $viddy->video = $filename;
      $viddy->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check to see if you have ffmpeg binaries on your device
- If you're using windows check if bin folder of ffmpeg is in your PATH
- Check to see if the config file for ffmpeg points to the right path

Comment: In my case(on windows) I had to set **ffmpeg_path** and **ffprobe_path** defined in config/medialibrary.php to paths of FFmpeg binaries with filenames: **E:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe** & **E:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe**